# Powershell 7.2.5 ConvertFrom-Json Outputting Array as One Object

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, aws-cli, powershell-7.2

I'm using the AWS CLI command `aws iam list-users` in Powershell 7.2.5 and trying to convert the output from JSON to a Powershell Object.

The JSON output of the above command looks like this (actual values omitted):

```json
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "UserName": "username1",
            "UserId": "userid1",
            "Arn": "arnid1",
            "CreateDate": "createddate"
        },
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "UserName": "username2",
            "UserId": "userid2",
            "Arn": "arnid2",
            "CreateDate": "createddate"
        },
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "UserName": "username3",
            "UserId": "userid3",
            "Arn": "arnid3",
            "CreateDate": "createddate"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try and run the following code to create an array of Powershell Objects:

```
$users = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $usersJson
```

The output comes out as a single Object:

```
Users
-----
{@{Path=/; UserName=username1; UserId=userid1; Arn=arnid1; CreateDate=createddate}, @{Path=/; UserName=username2; UserId=userid2; Arn=arnid2; CreateDate=createddate}, @{Path=/; UserName=username3; UserId=userid3; Arn=arnid3; CreateDate=createddate}}
```

Have read over countless posts and am now at a loss of what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're looking for `$users.Users` that will give you the array of objects

Comment: Ah wow I was over complicating that in my head. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

[Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72945835/powershell-7-2-5-convertfrom-json-outputting-array-as-one-object/72945988#comment128840891_72945835) was correct:

`$users.Users` shows all the entries as individual objects.